# Why rendering an svg tag to an ejs file is not recognized

Tags: node.js, svg, render, server-side, ejs

I try to use d3-node to make a chart in server side and try to render the new chart to ejs with following code:
        <%= svgChart %> 
when I use browser to view it, it only shows the svg tag contents like below:

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="960" height="400"><defs>                      <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[  .axis{font: 10px sans-serif;} .axis path,.axis line{fill: none;stroke: #000;shape-rendering: crispEdges;} .x.axis path{display: none;} ]]></style></defs><g transform="translate(40,20)"><path d="M20,32.4L20.430000000000003,32.4L20.86,32.4L21.290000000000003,32.4L21.720000000000002,32.4L22.150000000000002,32.4L22.580000000000002,32.4L23.01,32.4L23.44,32.4L23.87,32.4L24.299999999999997,32.4L24.73,32.4L25.16,32.4L25.590000000000003,32.4L26.02,32.4L26.450000000000003,32.4L26.88,32.4L27.310000000000002,32.4L27.740000000000002,32.4L28.17,32.4L28.6,32.4L29.03,32.4L29.46,32.4L29.89,32.4L30.32,32.4L30.75,32.4L31.18,32.4L31.61,32.4L32.04,32.4L32.47,32.4L32.9,32.4L33.33,32.4L33.76,32.4L34.190000000000005,32.4L34.620000000000005,32.4L35.050000000000004,32.4L35.480000000000004,32.4L35.910000000000004,32.4L36.34,32.4L36.77,32.4L37.2,32.4L37.63,32.4L38.06,32.4L38.489999999999995,32.4L38.92,32.4L39.35,32.4L39.78,32.4L40.21,32.4L40.64,32.4L41...............................
```

not showing the chart itself.
The svgChart contains the string of the svg tag. If I copy the svgChart content (the string) directly to the ejs, it will show the chart perfectly.

it seems ejs not able to render the tag contents when loading the page.It think the svgChart as a plain string.

My question: How to make the ejs recognize the svgChart as svg tag so it can show the svg chart insead of the text of the tag?

Comment: @Robert, It seems related to ejs rendering method. Seems when rendering, the code between the <%  %> only got the code itself, not have time to interpret it as svg code. Because I can copy the same svg code(tag) to the same ejs file directly, then client can get the chart perfectly instead of seeing the code. What I am trying  to do is to dynamically put that svg code(or svg tag)  in ejs file to let client have different chart whenever the data changed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

You can also include external SVG files directly in an EJS file like below.

```
<%- include ("path/to/file.svg") %>
```

Incidentally, this method also allows any text in the SVG to be rendered as real text in the page.

```
<svg height="30" width="200">
  <text x="0" y="15" fill="red">Hello from SVG</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to use `<%- svgChart %>` instead `<%= svgChart %>`.
By EJS documentation:

- <%= Outputs the value into the template (HTML escaped)
- <%- Outputs the
  unescaped value into the template

Comment: Thanks Lukkazs. Let me try this and will come back to you later. I had thought this is not the correct direction and tried other way for my previous application.